# PHP Отправка письма из черновика

Tags: php, email

Нужно через php отправить заранее подготовленное в черновиках письмо с вложением, перед отправкой предварительно изменив Тему письма.

В общем в кратце в чем смысл скрипта: 
На сайте в определенное время появляется код, скрипт стучит на сайт и ждет код. 
Как только код появился, нужно как можно быстрее отправить по 1 заранее подготовленному письму с вложением на почту с разных ящиков, 
Полученный код это тема письма.

Если отправлять через скрипт, то письмо не отправится пока вложение не будет загружено (а отправить нужно все и быстро) К примеру 30 писем, с 30 почтовых ящиков, у каждого письма вложение по 10мб, займет очень много времени, а если письмо уже будет заранее подготовлено в черновиках, то отправка будет в 100 раз быстре

Comment: А секретный код где? Я никому не расскажу про него.

Comment: Секретный код для чего?

Comment: Создаю в почтовом ящике(gmail к примеру) письмо с вложением, и сохраняю его в Черновиках, дальше мне нужно с помощью php скрипта подключится к почте, и отправить этот черновик (изменив при необходимости тему и получателя)
Для чего собственно это мне нужно, можно и просто через php отправить письмо с вложением, но если вложение будет большое, то скорость отправки естественно уменьшится, а отправить нужно очень быстро

Comment: На каком этапе не получается?

Comment: Отправить письмо с вложением через php не проблема, авторизируешься, тему письма, тело письма, вложение, все тут без проблем. А вот как именно из черновиков отправить заранее подготовленное письмо ничего найти не могу

Comment: А считать и положить к себе в БД?

Comment: Смысла нет, письма предварительно в черновики помещаются как раз для быстрой отправки, так как вложения в письмах до 10мб

Comment: Вам нужно копать в сторону gmail api, если такой имеется

Comment: Gmail API не подойдет, так как нужно отправлять по 1 письму с кучи почтовых ящиков, кстати не обязательно gmail